# Have we seen that item before?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

Toward the end of *The Last Jedi*

> Luke Skywalker gives Han Solo's dices to Leia (projection of them, actually).

Have we seen that item in previous episodes, especially in episodes IV-VI?

Comment: http://uk.ign.com/articles/2017/12/16/explaining-the-gold-dice-in-star-wars-the-last-jedi